# IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch and Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool are eating my CPU

Tags: ios, xcode

Does anyone know what these two: `IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch` and `Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool` are doing ?

Every time I have Xcode open these two are using so much CPU that my fans are at max speed.

I am using Xcode 9 beta 5 at the moment. Not sure if these all started with beta 5 or beta 4.

Can I do something to prevent them using so much CPU ?

Comment: Maybe the option of Automatically refresh views has something to do with this? did you have this option selected?

Comment: @ReinierMelian: yes it was selected, they I deselected for about 10 minutes, but no change. Maybe I need to wait more time

Comment: Try closing and opening your Xcode again

Comment: @ReinierMelian: I think this fixes the IBDesignablesAgentCocoaTouch issue, because right now, only the Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool is using a lot of my cpu.

Comment: No more ideas... I think you should maybe report a radar

Comment: I have got the same problem.

Comment: @CarlHung: I also closed Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool process from Activity Monitor, now I don't have this issue. But I guess it will appear again if u restart Xcode. I just close them manually as a temporary solution.

Comment: After some digging around I was able to reproduce the problem by dropping a UITextField onto a blank viewcontroller's view. That's it, no constraints, no changing of default values, just put a textfield on it and watch it go.

Answer (score 0):

Issue seems to be fixed in Xcode 9 Beta 6

Comment: try installing from fresh, cpu is quite high still but nowhere near as what it used to be

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue for a few hours and in the end I finally fixed it. IBCTT was eating up cpu and memory 5gb at one point and Xcode was unresponsive. I updated everything, cleared every cache and even tried throttling the tool but in the end the issue was simple but hard to detect. If that seems like your issue read on.

What you must do is clear all constraints on any view in the storyboard with errors if you are able to load it at least once. Then reset to suggested constraints and save.

If your storyboard has many views you want to **Editor -> Refactor to storyboard** the most complex or recently added/edited view.

*You may notice in the crash report that it mentions an error not reporting a reason. Seems that I was having an error that I couldn't detect since the storyboard wouldn't load anyways. Refactoring out the view with the issue, then loading it first on a fresh restart showed the error and allowed me to clear constraints immediately.*

Then restart Xcode by shutting down without force quitting to avoid the crash report and allow Xcode to start normally. Clear build folder then recompile.

This issue followed me through three installs of Xcode, 9.1 GM and 9.2 beta 1 and 2(9c34b) and a couple High Sierra beta updates (4 currently), so the issue seems to be deep within the AutoLayout engine. In all fairness to Apple constraints are a powerful idea but the variations involved on tools end is a nightmare.

Also my Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool is back to 84mb in Activity Monitor so I'm back to work....good luck!